# El significado de "un sujeto de onda"

Tags: significado-en-contexto

quisiera confirmar si "[el sujeto de onda](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?caifa.n)" significa que es un sujeto muy guay. ¡Muchas gracias¡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si "caifán" es "cae fine" entonces sería "que cae bien", "buena onda", "con buena vibra",  amable, simpático, etc con el cual fácilmente se puede interactuar o sintonizar.

"Que tiene onda", "Con onda" es una persona, "interesante",  "atractiva" que tiene un buen panorama que ofrecer.

"Sujeto de onda" no lo he escuchado.

https://www.asale.org/damer/onda

> b. ǁ   de ~.
> i.  loc. adj. Py, Ar, Ur. De moda. pop + cult → espon.

Si "De onda" se refiere al estilo, "que a anda a la moda" o con cosas llamativas o que representan a un cierto grupo, entonces tal vez eso se relacione con guay o cool y por lo mismo con la vestimenta de los Pachucos o a su sello.

Cuando alguien anda bien vestido también se puede llegar a escuchar algo como "¡Bien, ah!"

http://etimologias.dechile.net/?guay

No obstante esto puede variar según la región, la época y además usualmente se usan de forma intercambiable.

---

Yo creo que un "sujeto de la onda" es un persona que vivió esa época, que era parte y representaba a toda esa subcultura(Revolution Avenue de Tijuana), que se vestía de una forma determinada que hablaba spanglish, etc y que buscaba insertarse;  a diferencia de las comunidades lumpen o criminales, por lo tanto no se refiere a "sujeto de la onda" como igual a "vago", si no a uno que buscaba **insertarse en la onda, estar en la onda** o pertenecer a ella y el otro, en cambio, prefería vivir en la marginación y la delincuencia, caifanes y pachucos.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por las respuestas de todos!

Answer (score 0):

La palabra "sujeto de onda" se utiliza para referirse a un vago, un chulo... se relaciona con la palabra "caifán", sujeto preeminentemente de un barrio de ciudad. Chulo, tratante, aunque este término, "caifán", también se emplea para alguien que se viste elegantemente.

---

*La palabra Caifán está descrita como un sujeto preeminente en un barrio de la ciudad de acuerdo a la Real Academia Española. Puede definirse también a **un vago o a un sujeto de onda**.*

https://www.buenastareas.com/ensayos/Ca%C3%ADfanes/55707627.html

Comment: Deberías poner la citación entre comillas.

Comment: @Diego El OP preguntó sobre "sujeto de onda", no por caifán cuya definición ya estaba en el enlace que proporcionó, tu enlace no agrega nada nuevo, diría que caifán sería el que busca insertarse en la onda, en esa subcultura, y por el contrario a los marginales a los pachucos. No es que "sujeto de onda" signifique "vago".

Comment: Creo que esto debiera ser explicado en profundidad por un mexicano.

Comment: Ok, gracias por la indicación.